# Angular: ControlValueAccessor -> call to clearValidators() on parent causes child's validate method not being called

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I've been using the ControlValueAccessor for a while and recently I've come up a problema that I cannot find a way to fix.

I created some Components (using ControlValueAccessor) which have a FormGroup inside, with some special validation being applied.

On the parent component, I have some logic on where the child (the ControlValueAccessor component) is required or not.

In order to set the required validator I do the following:

```
        if(isRequired){
            this.form.controls.get('mycustomcontrol').clearValidators();
            this.form.controls.get('mycustomcontrol').setValidators(Validators.required);
        }else{
            this.form.controls.get('mycustomcontrol').clearValidators();
        }
```

When I do that, my child's 'validate' method stops being called by angular, hence not running my components custom validation logic anymore.

Does anyone know if this can be prevented or a way to tell angular to continue calling the validate on the child component?

I have created a sample stackblitz to show:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-reactive-forms-b4jztm?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you clearing the validators?

Comment: @WillAlexander I am clearing because that logic is related to another component (checkbox). Whenever the user changes the value, it should set the component required or not.

Answer (score 1):

When you call clearValidators on the parent form controls it also clears the validators on the child controls and that's why the validator of your custom component is no longer called.

A solution to this problem would be to set back the validator on your custom component after calling clearValidators :

```js
    // Get the current validators of the todo control
    const todoValidators = this.mainGroup.get('todo').validator;
    // Clear all validators
    this.mainGroup.clearValidators();
    // Sets back the validator of the todo control
    this.mainGroup.get('todo').setValidators(todoValidators);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-reactive-forms-5qczqo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: That is very nice! But is there a way to set and remove required validator on the component? To add the required validator seems easy, but I couldn't find a way to remove only the required later (while keeping the rest)

Comment: No unfortunatly it is not possible to remove individual validators. The setValidators method merges all validators into a single function control.validator. So the only way to remove a validator is to call the setValidator method to set all validators except the one you want removed.